# Deployed app on Github pages not loading assets/images and sass files

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my website for the first time on Github pages, however, after deployment, i am able to access the page either through my build folder 'https://shopeyin.github.io/Travlog/dist/index.html' or src folder 'https://shopeyin.github.io/Travlog/src/template.html' but my Sass files and images are not loading. What am i not doing right, my website is configured with webpack 5.
Here is an image of my folder structu
re.
[image]

Here is my webpack configuration

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Travlog App',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/template.html',
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible repo?

Comment: All your files are in the same folder with your html file ? Or all your files are in a subfolder of your html file ?

Comment: They are in the src folder while the build is in the dist folder @cat

Comment: If you want to your html site load your images you need to put the folder with images (in your case src) in the html file folder (in your case dist) and give de correct path to images in your html file (for an example src/img/cat.png). If I do not understand your problem right say me.

Comment: Html can acces the files only in his folder or in a subfolder for his folder.